# Unable to get the caret position from Outlook/Chrome/Edge, this code OK with most Apps

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I am unable to get the caret position from Outlook/Chrome/Edge while this code works OK with other Apps e.g. FireFox, Word, Excel.. Is it a some kind of security feature of browsers etc, any solutions?

For example GRAMMARLY tool displays it's icon properly next to caret on Chrome.

```
 MyH := GetForeGroundWindow();
 tid := GetWindowThreadProcessId(MyH, nil);

 try begin
 if AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId, tid, True) then begin
   if ( GetCaretPos(caretP) ) then begin
         if (caretP.x>0) or (caretP.y>0) then ClientToScreen (myh, caretP);
         x := caretP.x;
         y := caretP.y;
         if y>0 then y := y + 40;
         end;
   AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId, tid, False);
   end;
```

Comment: This works on window controls. A rendered website is not a window control - that's why whole engines exist for it. It's basically all custom-drawn. Try it on the settings window where you have controls.

Comment: Thanks, but why Firefox works ok? I can use any web page there and get caret pos..

Comment: This probably isn't a security issue, but a framework issue. An application that uses [Win32 carets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/carets) to implement the "blinking vertical text-input thing" will work with your code. But of course it is possible to make a blinking vertical line without asking Windows to do it for you. And if you implement this thing yourself manually, of course it will have no relation to Win32 carets. In addition, even if all carets were Win32 carets, there may be other problems. You are never guaranteed to be able to obtain data from other apps ...

Comment: ... like this. For instance, a single app may be different processes under the hood. Count your Chrome windows/tabs, and then your Chrome processes. There may be surprisingly little correlation between these numbers. Only the app's developers know the details, and unless their documentation makes any promises, you cannot rely on the details (and they may change any time).

Comment: Also TEAMS seem to fail to reveal the caret position.

Comment: What is your goal/reason for this? There might be a different way to solve it. For example, you might be able to use an app-specific extension, which is how Grammarly is able to do it.

Comment: Chrome uses a hidden window as parent of the browser. Are you sure you have the right window? Use the "Inspect.exe" tool, or spy++, to check.